# What is the encoding for JSON:API operators?

Tags: 8

I'm trying to filter JSON:API results based on the "greater than" operator (`>`).

The [filtering documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/filtering) lists the operators:

```
\Drupal\jsonapi\Query\EntityCondition::$allowedOperators = [
  '=', '<>',
  '>', '>=', '<', '<=',
  'STARTS_WITH', 'CONTAINS', 'ENDS_WITH',
  'IN', 'NOT IN',
  'BETWEEN', 'NOT BETWEEN',
  'IS NULL', 'IS NOT NULL',
];
```

But it also notes that the symbol operators need to be encoded:

```
&filter[a-label][condition][operator]=%3D  <- encoded "=" symbol
```

Which "encoding" is this referring to? What is the encoding for the other operators (`>`, `>=`, etc.)?  How do I look them up?

Comment: use PHP's `urlencode()`, see http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Hudri, here's the list:

- `=` `%3D`
- `<>` `%3C%3E`
- `>` `%3E`
- `>=` `%3E%3D`
- `<` `%3C`
- `<=` `%3C%3D`